# Aws Private Network Port Forwarding

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have 2 subnets, one private and one public. I need to renew the certificate by using letsencrypt on the private subnet. I’m able to do this by creating an instance in public and routing (dns, iptables). How can I do this by using AWS services in a private zone without creating a public instance? i.e "Nat Gateway".

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the [DNS-01 challenge type](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/), that way you don't need connectivity to your private instance.

If you wanted to allow your private instance access to the internet to use the HTTP-01 challenge type then you deploy a [NAT gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/nat-gateway-vpc-private-subnet/) or [NAT instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html) to your public subnet, and have the private subnet route 0.0.0.0/0 to that resource. A NAT instance is much cheaper, but you have to update / manage it. You can create either resource just during certificate renewal time, but it would be much easier to set up automatic renewals which means the NAT resources runs all that time.

Certbot supports [automate renewals](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#automated-renewals).